# How to use ON DUPLICATE KEY update in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
INSERT INTO policy_consent_status (patien_ID,policy_ID,PS_ID)
VALUES
  ((SELECT patient_ID FROM patient WHERE first_name="Christine"),(SELECT policy_ID 
    FROM policy WHERE policy_name="PI"),6)
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE
  patien_ID = VALUES((SELECT patient_ID FROM patient WHERE first_name="Christine")),
  policy_ID = VALUES((SELECT policy_ID FROM policy WHERE policy_name="PI"))
  PS_ID = 6
```

I have to insert on new and update on existing

Comment: You should start by writing a select query which selects from patient joining policy. Get that to work and then dump the values clauses - see the manual for examples of how you use insert..select..on duplicate key https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Show destination table structure. What unique index will cause ON DUPLICATE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, the argument to `VALUES` has to be the name of a column; it returns the value that would have been inserted into the new row. If you want to use some other value, just put the expression there, without `VALUES`.

But you don't need multiple subqueries. Use a `SELECT` query as the source of the values to insert.

Also, you don't need to assign the values of the columns that are part of the unique key, only the columns that you want to update. I assume in your table the unique key is the combination of `patient_id` and `policy_id`.

```
INSERT INTO policy_consent_status (patient_ID,policy_ID,PS_ID)
SELECT patient_id, policy_id, 6
FROM patient 
CROSS JOIN policy
WHERE first_name="Christine"
AND policy_name="PI"
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE PS_ID = VALUES(PS_ID)
```

Comment: I tried to do this but every time instead of updating the data it is inserting a new row

Comment: @ChristineShaji do you have defined unique fields patient_id, policy_id in that table???

Comment: @Zeljka This table is a relational table and patient_ID and policy_ID are foreign keys.

Comment: @it doesn't matter if its relation table or not, if you want to use `ON DUPLICATE KEY` those fields needs to be defined as unique in that table